# How to resolve an xml attribute error from a service reference created from a WSDL file

Tags: java, c#, xml, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to write a C# client application that consumes a Java web service, provided by a 3rd party supplier.

Creating the service reference directly from the URL had issues due to incorrectly formatted XML. Using good old cut and paste I created a text file with the WSDL data and fixed the formatting issues and then created the service reference using the file path.

Now that I have my service reference I'm getting an XML validation error when I call any method on the service client. I also get the error just calling the Open() method on the client.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The top XML element 'request' from namespace '' references distinct types TestApp1.TheService.CreateBulkOffers and TestApp1.TheService.WSCreateBulkOffersResponse. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileAccessor(Accessor accessor, NameTable accessors)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileLocalAccessor(ElementAccessor accessor, String ns)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
```

The snippet of the WSDL relating to TestApp1.TheService.CreateBulkOffers and TestApp1.TheService.WSCreateBulkOffersResponse is below:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="CreateBulkOffers">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xsd:extension base="ns93:WSCommonInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="securityPolicyName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="folderID" nillable="true" type="xsd:long">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="templateName" type="xsd:string">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="offers" type="ns93:WSBulkOfferInfo">
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="WSCreateBulkOffersResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="status" type="ns93:WSRequestStatus" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="offerInfo" nillable="true" type="ns93:WSOfferInfoStatus" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

The classes generated from the WSDL are here:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://webservices.CustomerServices/3.0")]
public partial class CreateBulkOffers : WSCommonInfo {

    private string securityPolicyNameField;

    private System.Nullable<long> folderIDField;

    private string templateNameField;

    private WSBulkOfferInfo[] offersField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string securityPolicyName {
        get {
            return this.securityPolicyNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.securityPolicyNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("securityPolicyName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public System.Nullable<long> folderID {
        get {
            return this.folderIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.folderIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("folderID");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public string templateName {
        get {
            return this.templateNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("templateName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("offers", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public WSBulkOfferInfo[] offers {
        get {
            return this.offersField;
        }
        set {
            this.offersField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("offers");
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://webservices.CustomerServices/3.0")]
public partial class WSCreateBulkOffersResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private WSRequestStatus statusField;

    private WSOfferInfoStatus[] offerInfoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public WSRequestStatus status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("status");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("offerInfo", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public WSOfferInfoStatus[] offerInfo {
        get {
            return this.offerInfoField;
        }
        set {
            this.offerInfoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("offerInfo");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Any advice on how to resolve this error would be great.**

**Edit - Full exception added**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'request'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The top XML element 'request' from namespace '' references distinct types TestApp1.TheService.CreateBulkOffers and TestApp1.TheService.WSCreateBulkOffersResponse. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileAccessor(Accessor accessor, NameTable accessors)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ReconcileLocalAccessor(ElementAccessor accessor, String ns)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.XmlSerializerImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlName elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean isEncoded, String mappingKey)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, String mappingKey)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.LoadBodyMapping(MessageDescription message, String mappingKey, MessagePartDescriptionCollection& rpcEncodedTypedMessageBodyParts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.CreateMessageInfo(MessageDescription message, String key)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.CreateFormatter()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Open()
   at TestApp1.Program.LaunchService() in c:\Work\TestApp1\TestApp1\Program.cs:line 36
```

Comment: Can you show the full `ToString()` output for the exception, including all inner exceptions?